# User higher order functions in C++ 14

Tags: c++, arduino, higher-order-functions

I'd like to create a class that accepts a function which was created by another function in Arduino. The "closest" I got after searching and a lot of trial and error (without `std::function` as we're in Arduino and C++ 14):

in `foo.h`

```cpp
class Foo {
  private:
    template<typename Functor>
    Functor _lambda;

  public:
    template<typename Functor>
    Foo(Functor lambda);

    static auto create_lambda(int a) {
      return [a](int b) mutable { ... }
    }
};
```

in `foo.cpp`

```cpp
template<typename Functor>
Foo::Foo (Functor lambda) : _lambda(lambda) {}
```

in `bar.cpp`

```cpp
new Foo(Foo::create_lambda(2));
```

The code above produces a number of errors including:

```
error: data member '_lambda' cannot be a member template
error: 'Foo::Foo(Functor) [with Functor = Foo::create_lambda(int)::<lambda(bool)>]', declared using local type 'Foo::create_lambda(int)::<lambda(bool)>', is used but never defined
```

Also, happy to go with C++ 17 if that helps.

Comment: whats wrong with your code?

Comment: Class members cannot be templates, only class methods can. Sorry, C++ does not work this way. Your entire class must be a template. Also a number of other, fundamental, things must be changed in order to make this work (for example, putting template definitions in `.cpp` files always ends in tears). The same is true for C++17, and likely every other future C++ version. Just use `std::function`, it's much easier.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, sounds all good except that the Arduino environment they're running in likely doesn't have `std::function`, hence why they're asking to go without.  The common AVR-based Arduino environment provide something approaching a C99 hosted C standard library, but no C++ standard library at all; no `std::swap` or `std::array`, let alone `std::function`.

Comment: So you ask for an implementation of `std::function`  for arduino.

Comment: If only starless lambda is passed to constructor then just use pointer to function.

Answer (score 2):

The class has to be templated, rather than the member:

```cpp
// Put this whole thing in the header file. 
// It has to go there b/c templates have to be in the header.
template<class F>
class Foo {
    F func;
   public:
    Foo() = default;
    Foo(Foo const&) = default;
    Foo(Foo&&) = default;
    Foo(F f) : func(f) {}

    // Example invoke member function
    int invoke(int value) {
        return func(value);
    }
};
```

In C++17, we can make it figure out the type of `F` automatically when making a `Foo` by adding a template deduction guide for `Foo`:

```cpp
// Put this after the class declaration
template <class F>
Foo(F) -> Foo<F>;
```

Then, we can use it pretty easily!

```cpp
// Template parameter is implicit
Foo myFoo = [](int x) { return x * x; };
// myFoo now has type Foo<(anonymous lambda)>
```

If you *absolutely need* runtime polymorphism, you can have an interface that each `Foo<F>` extends:

```cpp
class Invokable {
    virtual int invoke(int) = 0;
    virtual ~Invokable() = default;  
};

template <class F>
class Foo : Invokable {
    // ...
};
```

This article about the way `std::function` is implemented provides more details than I can in a stack overflow post: https://shaharmike.com/cpp/naive-std-function/

**Addendum:** [You can see a working example here.](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:12,endLineNumber:6,positionColumn:12,positionLineNumber:6,selectionStartColumn:12,selectionStartLineNumber:6,startColumn:12,startLineNumber:6),source:%27%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0A%0A//+Put+this+whole+thing+in+the+header+file.+%0A//+It+has+to+go+there+b/c+templates+have+to+be+in+the+header.%0Atemplate%3Cclass+F%3E%0Aclass+Foo+%7B%0A++++F+func%3B%0A+++public:%0A++++Foo()+%3D+default%3B%0A++++Foo(Foo+const%26)+%3D+default%3B%0A++++Foo(Foo%26%26)+%3D+default%3B%0A++++Foo(F+f)+:+func(f)+%7B%7D%0A%0A++++//+Example+invoke+member+function%0A++++int+invoke(int+value)+%7B%0A++++++++return+func(value)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A//+Put+this+after+the+class+declaration%0Atemplate+%3Cclass+F%3E%0AFoo(F)+-%3E+Foo%3CF%3E%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++//+Template+parameter+is+implicit%0A++++Foo+myFoo+%3D+%5B%5D(int+x)+%7B+return+x+*+x%3B+%7D%3B%0A%0A++++for(int+i+%3D+0%3B+i+%3C%3D+10%3B+i%2B%2B)+%7B%0A++++++++printf(%22The+square+of+%25i+is+%25i%5Cn%22,+i,+myFoo.invoke(i))%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,tree:%271%27,wrap:%270%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+10.1+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27),(h:compiler,i:(compiler:g101,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-O3%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+10.1+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

When compiled with optimization, the assembly is extremely compact. One of the benefits of C++ is that there's no overhead in using lambdas or templates, and they're entirely transparent to the compiler.

(Virtual functions are NOT transparent, which is why I do my best to avoid them, but sometimes you really need runtime polymorphism)

```
.LC0:
        .string "The square of %i is %i\n"
main:
        push    rbx
        xor     ebx, ebx
.L2:
        mov     edx, ebx
        mov     esi, ebx
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        xor     eax, eax
        imul    edx, ebx
        add     ebx, 1
        call    printf
        cmp     ebx, 11
        jne     .L2
        xor     eax, eax
        pop     rbx
        ret
```